# Repeating results in a loop in R

Tags: r

does someone know how to fix it? The loop is not working as it is returning the same 2 rows over the entire matrix. But the columns are correct. This problem started after we added 'q','p' into the loop. So we suspect that the 'q','p' did not sync in with 'j' ('j' is the county's column number).

```
OLS.table <- matrix(nrow = length(colnames(R.index)) * 2, ncol = 6)

rownames(OLS.table) <- c("GE", "", "FR", "", "NL", "", "BE", "", "IT", "", "SP", "", "AU", "", "CH", "", "IN", "", "MX", "", "SA", "", "PO", "", "MA", "")
colnames(OLS.table) <- rep(c("5%", "7.5%", "10%"), 2)

percentage <- c(0.05, 0.075, 0.1)

for (j in 1:length(colnames(R.index))) {
  for (q in seq(1, length(colnames(R.index)) * 2, 2)) {
    for (a in 1:3) {
      for (i in sort(percentage)[a]) {
        p <- q + 1
        start <- round(i * length(R.index[, j]))
        # right tail
        size <- sort(coredata(R.index[, j]), decreasing = TRUE)[1:start]
        Rank <- sort(rank(coredata(R.index[, j]), na.last = FALSE), decreasing = TRUE)[1:start]
        # left tail
        size1 <- sort(coredata(R.index[, j]), decreasing = FALSE)[1:start]
        Rank1 <- sort(rank(coredata(R.index[, j]), na.last = FALSE), decreasing = FALSE)[1:start]

        y <- log(Rank - 1 / 2)
        y1 <- log(Rank1 - 1 / 2)
        size.log <- log(size)
        size1.log <- log(size1)

        OLS.table[q, a] <- round(coef(lm(y ~ size.log))[2], 3)
        OLS.table[q, a + 3] <- round(coef(lm(y1 ~ size1.log))[2], 3)
        OLS.table[p, a] <- round(sd(size), 3)
        OLS.table[p, a + 3] <- round(sd(size1), 3)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The result looks like this

```
    > OLS.table
      5%  7.5%    10%     5%   7.5%    10%
GE 0.507 0.672  0.825 24.261 19.558 16.538
   8.553 9.752 10.508  3.035  3.862  4.654
FR 0.507 0.672  0.825 24.261 19.558 16.538
   8.553 9.752 10.508  3.035  3.862  4.654
NL 0.507 0.672  0.825 24.261 19.558 16.538
   8.553 9.752 10.508  3.035  3.862  4.654
BE 0.507 0.672  0.825 24.261 19.558 16.538
   8.553 9.752 10.508  3.035  3.862  4.654
IT 0.507 0.672  0.825 24.261 19.558 16.538
   8.553 9.752 10.508  3.035  3.862  4.654
SP 0.507 0.672  0.825 24.261 19.558 16.538
   8.553 9.752 10.508  3.035  3.862  4.654
AU 0.507 0.672  0.825 24.261 19.558 16.538
   8.553 9.752 10.508  3.035  3.862  4.654
CH 0.507 0.672  0.825 24.261 19.558 16.538
   8.553 9.752 10.508  3.035  3.862  4.654
IN 0.507 0.672  0.825 24.261 19.558 16.538
   8.553 9.752 10.508  3.035  3.862  4.654
MX 0.507 0.672  0.825 24.261 19.558 16.538
   8.553 9.752 10.508  3.035  3.862  4.654
SA 0.507 0.672  0.825 24.261 19.558 16.538
   8.553 9.752 10.508  3.035  3.862  4.654
PO 0.507 0.672  0.825 24.261 19.558 16.538
   8.553 9.752 10.508  3.035  3.862  4.654
MA 0.507 0.672  0.825 24.261 19.558 16.538
   8.553 9.752 10.508  3.035  3.862  4.654
```

Comment: Perhaps simplify to a succession of loops, processing your [ ,j] related result, then processing q:a:i, and the mysterious p. Additionally, your `y`, `y1` : `size1.log` will always be the last j seen, which many or may not be what you want.

Comment: @user438383 what I want is each j country data in R.index should be processed, then the results be input into OLS.table, a and i is to apply the percentage to the formula. q is to arrange coeficent into table while q is to apply the standard deviation into the table respectively. what do you mean by simplify to a succession of loops? because I tried to move the loop but it doesn't work